# Disable a single (or small number of) emoji in Slack

Tags: slack, emoji

How do we remove the middle finger emoji from Slack's symbol set for our team?

Comment: I would like to disable some emoji too.  But it seems like it is not a feature yet as far as I can tell.

Comment: Speculation: Is it possible to change the appearance of the emoji?

Comment: For others reading this, it is possible to add / change custom emojis (e.g. the rainbow parrot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an official feature but there is a theoretical workaround, if you don't want users using the middle finger emoji in conversations. **The easiest way is to delete messages containing the content.**

To do this you must [create a bot](https://slack.com/signin?redir=%2Fservices%2Fnew%2Fbot) with moderator privileges, and ask it to delete any messages containing the phrase or prevent such

> :middle_finger:

This is the middle finger symbols emoji code. Theoretically the bot will prevent them from ever posting a message that contains this symbol. If your trying to ban other emojis as well, you can find a list of codes [here](https://www.webpagefx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/)